# Broadcasting SMS messages to all users on the nearest signal tower

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to communicate with the nearest signal tower and send broadcast messages to all users who are connected with the nearest tower?

My goal is to do this in an Android app for SMS-based marketing.

Comment: I really hope not.

Answer (score 1):

### No, you can't do that.

If that were possible, you'd be getting constantly flooded with spam messages from people setting up devices to send advertising messages to everyone in the area.

For SMS specifically, SMS messages contain [exactly one address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40#Addresses), in the form of a phone number.

For shorter range, there used to be an API that you could use to send a notification to nearby users via a Bluetooth beacon, but that was [shut down](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html) for exactly the same reason you can't do this with SMS: people used it for spam.